# s[ ] is an array.&s should give address of decayed pointer

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

After initialising character array name and address refers to same. s[] is an array. so it decays to pointer **s**, **&s** should give the address of pointer **s**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char s[]="Get Organised! learn C!";
   printf("%u %s\n",&s[2],&s[2] );
   printf("%u %s\n",s,s );  /* This line and below line is equivalent*/
   printf("%u %s\n",&s,&s ); /* Please Explain */
   printf("%u %s\n",s[2],s[2] );
   printf("%u %s\n",s[3],s[3] );
   return 0;
}
```

%u is just used to see what is going inside.

Comment: It's all undefined behaviour. `%u` requires that you're passing an `int` or `unsigned int`, and you don't.

Comment: No, I am asking **printf("%s\n",s );**
   **printf( %s\n",&s );** gives same answer

Comment: It is because an array decays to a pointer.

Comment: s[ ] is an array. so it decays to pointer **s** , **&s** should give the address of pointer **s**

Comment: No, &s gives address of the array.

Comment: Ack, you changed the question on me.  Short answer - `s` is *not* converted to a pointer when it is the operand of the unary `&` or `sizeof` operators, so the *values* of `s` and `&s` are the same (address of the first element of the array), but the *types* are different (`char *` and `char (*)[28]`, respectively).

Comment: @JohnBode : - I copied your answer. I could not understand that well so i put in notepad so that i can read it later.Thank You very Much

Comment: Summary 'C is inconsistent and borderline insane when it comes to array handling'.  Any sane language would have forced to to pass '&array' to pass by address but, unfortunately, C was written by Unix developers who needed to handle text as easily as possible, (text is all they understand), so no '&'.

Comment: Even if `&s` did give you the address of the pointer it decays to, that wouldn't make sense, because that pointer is *not* a variable. (It would be like saying `&1` to get the address of `1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the below, `s` is an [array 100 of char](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+s%5B100%5D).  When is is passed to `printf()`, array `s` is converted to the value and type of the address of first element.  So `printf()` is given a `char *`.

`&s` is the **address of an array 100 of char**.  It has an equivalent *value* as `s`, yet a different type.

```
char s[100]="Whatever";
printf(some_format,s);
printf(some_format,&s);
```

To properly print addresses of variables, literals, cast to `(void*)` and use `"%p"`.  The print out *typically* lacks any description of the *type*  of the variable.

```
printf("%p\n",(void*) s);
printf("%p\n",(void*) &s);
```

Output

```
0x28cbdc
0x28cbdc
```

To see an effect of the type difference:

```
printf("%zu\n",sizeof *(s));
printf("%zu\n",sizeof *(&s));
```

Output

```
1
100
```

[@john bode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35925087/s-is-an-array-so-it-decays-to-pointer-s-s-should-give-the-address/35925990#comment59509032_35925087) also suggested this earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of undefined behaviour first:

```
int main() {
  char const string [] = "hello";
  printf("%p %p\n", (void *) string, (void *) &string);
  return 0;
}
```

You get (probably, that's target dependent) the same address printed here because the first expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of the array while the second is a pointer to the whole array (which most likely happens to start at its first element)

```
string == &(string[0]) // this is often called decaying
```

The type of the expression `string` (or more precisely the expression it decays to) is `char const *` whereas the type of `&string` is `char const (*array)[6]`, so they're not "the same".

The reason that `&string` is **not** a pointer to a pointer is simple: The C standard explicitly forbids array expressions prefixed with the address of operator (`&`) (or inside an `sizeof` operator) to be implicitly converted to a pointer.